# HV9910C select Rt resistor

Tags: led, led-driver

I'm working on a board that has to control some LED chains. Each chain requires about 17-18V (power rail is 24V) with a nominal current of about 450 mA.

An MCU will provide the PWM to control the LED brightness. I selected [HV9910C](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/268/20005323A-947801.pdf) as a LED driver. The LEDs are placed quite close to the driver board (< 10 cm) and a key point is to avoid flickering, especially at low PWM values.

Reading the datasheet in chapter 3.0 Application Information I read:

> Constant frequency peak current mode control has an inherent disadvantage – at duty cycles greater than 0.5, the control scheme goes into subharmonic oscillations. To prevent this, an artificial slope is typically added to the current sense waveform. This slope compensation scheme will affect the accuracy of the LED current in the present form.

> However, a constant off-time peak current control scheme does not have this problem and can easily operate at duty cycles greater than 0.5. This control scheme also gives inherent input voltage rejection, making the LED current almost insensitive to input voltage variations.  However, this scheme leads to variable frequency operation and the frequency range depends greatly on the input and output voltage variation.

In my system, I have a stable input voltage of 24V, so I'm not interested in voltage-variations rejection.

It's not clear to me how to decide which's control scheme is better for my application: it says "the slope compensation scheme will affect the accuracy of the LED current" but I cannot find *how much* the current is affected! Are we talking about 1-2% or 10-20%?

About the constant off-time mode, the chapter 3.3 Oscillator says:

> If the resistor is connected between RT and GATE, HV9910C operates in a constant off-time mode and the above equation determines the off-time.

But again, I don't understand how to choose the appropriate off-time and how to calculate the frequency range that "depends greatly on the input and out-put voltage variation".

Would you mind clarifying how to design such a LED driver?

Comment: I dont know the answer, but Is accuracy important for you? (do you want your leds to draw a specific amount of current?)
These oscillations (i think) wont have any visible effect on the viewer (if you want to use them as light sources for your desk for example).

So, if the above are true, i would suggest to just use a mosfet to control the current that goes to the leds.

Comment: LED flickering at low currents is the bane of all DC-DC drivers. I've searched high-and-low for a way to mitigate it, but found nothing helpful except faster PWM freq.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios, the LEDs are for specific purpose (plant growing) so, yes, the amount of current is important. The problem is how much those oscillations will affect the current.

Comment: @rdtsc, do you have a rule of thumb about how much "faster" the PWM frequency should be at least?

Comment: For plants, it may not matter much. But our eyes exhibit a phenomena called [persistence of vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision) which is to say at some frequency such as 60Hz, at first glance, light *seems* to be continuous. But move your head, the light, or wave your fingers in front of it (light slits), and the pulsing can be detected, up to a kilohertz or more.  Anyways, the driver's PWM input is typically limited to a few kHz at best, and is usually the limiting factor.